# Setting up basic nginx reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy

Unfortunately, my work requires me to use Apache Tomcat. The Tomcat application is running on http://127.0.0.1:8080/. I'd like to get a reverse proxy going so I can have http://mydomain.com/tomcat/some/extra/stuff proxy from http://127.0.0.1:8080/some/extra/stuff. This is what I'm trying so far:

```
location /tomcat {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    rewrite ^/tomcat(/.*) $1 break;
}
```

This results in http://mydomain.com/tomcat/meow/cat redirecting to http://mydomain.com/meow/cat which is not what I want. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the rewrite rule, that config will map domain.com/tomcat/ to http://127.0.0.1:8080/ so you don't need to rewrite the directory

Comment: I want http://127.0.0.1:8080/whatever to be accessed by http://mypublicip/tomcat/whatever rather than http://mypublicip/whatever

Comment: Yes, that will work fine, you don't need rewrite rules. Anything with a sub-directory of /tomcat will be proxied. http://site/tomcat/folder/file.html will map to http://127[...]/folder/file.html